# iOS - Build Freezes When I Build To Device but Not in Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, ios4

I'm curious if someone can help me figure out what is going on...

I have an app that works fine in the simulator with no warnings or errors but when I try to even build with the device selected it appears to freeze. I've left it building for over 20minutes with no luck.

The application uses a large number of animated PNG sequence and a few videos but that didn't appear to be a problem until today.

Any insight would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an odd problem with XCode compressing the PNGs in my project.

Turned off the PNG compression and it complied in no time.

Answer (score 0):

What has changed in your environment since yesterday?
Can you back off the number of images to say 3 small ones, and one short video, and see if it builds then?  Then add them back in a few at a time to see where it's breaking.  Divide an conquer.